# Em que tag colocar o formulário?

Tags: html5

Eu criei uma página e dentro desta página tem um formulário. Até aí, tudo ok. Mas eu coloco o formulário dentro de que tag? Semanticamente falando, dentro de um section, de um article, de um section e um article, ou de uma div? Ainda estou um pouco confuso com a semântica quando sai do usual. Pesquisei no Google, mas não obtive respostas satisfatórias.

```
section
form
form
/section
```

ou

```
article
form
/form
/article
```

ou

```
section
article
form
/form
/article
/section
```

ou

```
div
form
/form
/div
```

Comment: Resposta rápida: não existe resposta. O elemento pai dependerá da [outline](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/247160/5878) da sua página. Se o formulário faz parte do conteúdo principal, estará dentro da `article`, mas poderá estar dentro da `article > section`  se a outline exigir isso, ou ainda em `article > section > div`. Se o formulário é secundário na página, estará fora da `article`, em qualquer combinação de elementos novamente. Em relação ao formulário, não faz diferença, o que muda é a outline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na documentação da W3C aparentemente não existe referencia a estrutura semântica de onde o `form` deve vir na página. Já na documentação da Mozilla eles colocam na verdade a `section` dentro do `form`!

Mas o ponto mais importante, e que tanto a W3C quando a Mozilla abordam é a estrutura semântica do `form` em si.

[Veja o modelo proposto pela Mozilla abaixo](https://github.com/mdn/learning-area/blob/master/html/forms/html-form-structure/payment-form.html):

> Here you'll see that we are wrapping the contact information fields
>   inside a distinct `<section>` element.

**OBS:** Tente contar quantas `<div>` existem nesse modelo!

```css
h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

form {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 1em;
}

div+div {
    margin-top: 1em;
}

label span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 120px;
    text-align: right;
}

input, textarea {
    font: 1em sans-serif;
    width: 250px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #999;
}

input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio] {
    width: auto;
    border: none;
}

input:focus, textarea:focus {
    border-color: #000;
}

textarea {
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 5em;
    resize: vertical;
}

fieldset {
    width: 250px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-left: 136px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
}

button {
    margin: 20px 0 0 124px;
}

label {
  position: relative;
}

label em {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
        <h1>Payment form</h1>
        <p>Required fields are followed by <strong><abbr title="required">*</abbr></strong>.</p>
        <section>
            <h2>Contact information</h2>
            <fieldset>
              <legend>Title</legend>
              <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label for="title_1">
                      <input type="radio" id="title_1" name="title" value="M." >
                      Mister
                    </label>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <label for="title_2">
                      <input type="radio" id="title_2" name="title" value="Ms.">
                      Miss
                    </label>
                  </li>
              </ul>
            </fieldset>
            <p>
              <label for="name">
                <span>Name: </span>
                <strong><abbr title="required">*</abbr></strong>
              </label>
              <input type="text" id="name" name="username">
            </p>
            <p>
              <label for="mail">
                <span>E-mail: </span>
                <strong><abbr title="required">*</abbr></strong>
              </label>
              <input type="email" id="mail" name="usermail">
            </p>
            <p>
              <label for="pwd">
                <span>Password: </span>
                <strong><abbr title="required">*</abbr></strong>
              </label>
              <input type="password" id="pwd" name="password">
            </p>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h2>Payment information</h2>
            <p>
              <label for="card">
                <span>Card type:</span>
              </label>
              <select id="card" name="usercard">
                <option value="visa">Visa</option>
                <option value="mc">Mastercard</option>
                <option value="amex">American Express</option>
              </select>
            </p>
            <p>
              <label for="number">
                <span>Card number:</span>
                <strong><abbr title="required">*</abbr></strong>
              </label>
                <input type="text" id="number" name="cardnumber">
            </p>
            <p>
              <label for="date">
                <span>Expiration date:</span>
                <strong><abbr title="required">*</abbr></strong>
                <em>formatted as mm/yy</em>
              </label>
              <input type="text" id="date" name="expiration">
            </p>
        </section>
        <section>
            <p> <button type="submit">Validate the payment</button> </p>
        </section>
    </form>
```

Contou quantas `<div>` tinham? Isso mesmo **ZERO**! Reparou como o `form` é montado de maneira minuciosa e 100% semântico. Essa tem que ser a preocupação principal.

## Palavras finais:

Então onde o `form` está na estrutura não importa muito. Se seu `form` é o assunto principal da página coloque o `<h1>` nele e coloque ele posicionado mais para cima na página, pois os leitores de tela começam de cima para baixo. Se puder faça um teste básico, tente navegar em sua tela apertando o <kbd>TAB</kbd> para ver como o foco vai mudando. Se precisar faça correções usando o `tabindex` ([leia mais sobre tabindex aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex))

- Documentação **W3C**: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html
- Documentação **Mozilla**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/How_to_structure_an_HTML_form

---

**Informações adicionais sobre acessibilidade**

Segundo ai W3C WAI e a WebAim vc pode e deve usar os `aria-labelledby` na construção do formulário para ajudar os leitores de tela. Vc pode se informar mais aqui https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/instructions/#using-aria-labelledby

EX: `<input type="password" name="password" id="password" aria-describedby="password">`

Além disso, vc também pode usar os `role` para interagir melhor com os leitores de tela. *Basic form hints* da Mozilla [Nessa documentação vc pode se informar melhor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/forms/Basic_form_hints).

EX: Repare no `role` na section e no `aria-required` no `input`

```
<form>
    <section role="form">
      <label for="name">* Name:</label>
      <input type="text" value="name" id="name" aria-required="true"/>
    </section>  
</form>
```

**Importante:** Se vc tem uma `div` que semanticamente não é um `buttom`, mas faz o papel de `buttom`, pois pode ser clicado etc, é **imprescindível** que vc use esses atributos de `role` e `aria` para os leitores de tela identificarem esse "componente" como algo clicável e aria ativa! Documentação completa **W3C ARIA**, lá tem tudo sobre os `roles` e os `arias` https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/ (2017)

EX: Mais uma vez repare no `role` na section e no `aria-checked`

```
<div role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" tabindex="0">
    Escolher esse
</div>
```

Vc ainda pode trabalhar melhor seu forme usando os `microdatas` do Schema por exemple e colocando `itemscope` `itemtype` `itemprop` nos elementos. Aqui tem um modelo para LocalBusiness http://schema.org/LocalBusiness